# ProgressBar value is changing but the gui is not changing on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to implement a `ProgressBar` which will be shown during file transfer.

The file transfer is done with a `BackgroundWorker`.

Just to check the functionality I've tried to make progress from the main thread and nothing happens.

The code:

```
myProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
myProgressBar.Maximum = numOfPackets;
```

Here is the background worker code...

and then:

```
myProgressBar.IsEnabled = true;

for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
{
    myProgressBar.Value = i;
    myProgressBar.UpdateDefaultStyle();
}
```

Why nothing changes?

Comment: Are you sure `buff.Length` is greater than zero? So is `numOfPackets`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's extremely bad to do IO or file  transfer on background thread because during file transfer or IO operation CPU is not  getting used so your background thread is not doing anything but waiting for IO to  comlpete and you are wasting one thread which in turn lead to wastage of memory .one more disadvantage is  your UI will become unresponsive of file transfer takes considerable amount of time, even though you are doing it on background thread.

I can keep on writing disadvantages of doing IO work on background thread but you  should request one  documentation on doing IO asynchronously in. Net. 
Background threads are for  CPU intensive work like some heavy computation where CPU is involved.

You should  use asynchronous IO. Use async and await. Please read about asynchronous IO. 
I have one  sample example of whatever you are doing  with pure asynchronous IO with progressbar and responsive UI. I will write it tomorrow.

**
**Below is the asynchronus io file transfer code, assuming all files are of same size for progress updation
Below mentioned code will work and application will not hang even when you move the window while files are being transffered.**
**

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="asyncawait.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="514" Width="674">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,4">
        <ScrollViewer Name="scrv_Log" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="397" Margin="33,61,0,67">
            <ListBox VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" ItemsSource="{Binding Datas,Mode=OneWay}" Background="White" Foreground="Red"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock Height="40" Width="70" FontSize="10" Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding FileCounter,Mode=OneWay}" Margin="540,281,56,158"></TextBlock>
        <Button Foreground="Black" IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnabled}" Click="Button_Click"  Height="40" Width="40" RenderTransformOrigin="4.65,0.425" Margin="540,210,86,229"></Button>
        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progressvalue,Mode=OneWay}"  Name="prg" Foreground="Green"  Height="20" Width="600" Margin="23,453,44.2,7"></ProgressBar>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=prg,Path=Value}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0}%" Height="25" Margin="253,0,295.2,22"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <TextBox Background='AliceBlue' HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="525,109,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

****Here is the code behind which does asynnchronous IO**

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
        public double Progressvalue
        {
            get
            {
                return _Progressvalue;

            } 
            set
            {
                if(value!=_Progressvalue)
                {
                    _Progressvalue=value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
         }
        private Double _Progressvalue=0;
        private bool _IsEnabled=true;

        public Boolean IsButtonEnabled { 
            get
            {
                return _IsEnabled;
             }

            set
            {
                if(value!=_IsEnabled)
                {
                    _IsEnabled = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private async  void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsButtonEnabled = false;
            await AsyncTransferFiles();
            IsButtonEnabled = true;
            scrv_Log.ScrollToBottom();

        }

        private String fileCounter;
         public String FileCounter
        {
            get
            { return fileCounter; }
            set
            {
                if (value != fileCounter)
                {
                    fileCounter = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }







        private ObservableCollection<String> _Datas = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<String> Datas
        {
            get
            {
                return _Datas;
            }
        }
         private async Task AsyncTransferFiles()
        {

            var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Data1").ToList();
            int totalCount = fileNames.Count;
            pr = (double)1 / totalCount;
            int counter = 0;
            var progress = new Progress<double>();
            progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
                {

                   Progressvalue = Double.Parse(e.ToString());

                };
            foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
            {
                await (CopyFileAsync(fileName, "C:\\GradebookTemp1\\" + fileName.Split('\\')[2], progress, ++counter));
            }
        }



         double pr = 0.0;
         public async Task CopyFileAsync(string sourcePath, string destinationPath,IProgress<double> progress ,int fileCounter)
         {
             using (Stream source = File.Open(sourcePath,FileMode.Open))
             {
                 using (Stream destination = File.Create(destinationPath))
                 {
                     await source.CopyToAsync(destination);
                     progress.Report((int)(pr*fileCounter*100));
                     FileCounter = fileCounter.ToString();
                     Datas.Add("Copied File: " + sourcePath);
                     scrv_Log.ScrollToBottom();

                 }
             }

         }

        private void EnableButton()
        {
            IsButtonEnabled = true;
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName=null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if(null!=handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your guiding! i'll look into async/await tasks , i am looking forward the example you will give , many thanks!                               I want to implement the best practice withmy code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try it

Comment: Please upvote it so that it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

For wpf you can use this:

```
this.Dispacher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> { for(int i...)...; }));
```

Answer (score 0):

That solution worked once for me:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            progBar.Value = i;
            progBar.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate () { };

    public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
    {
        uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
    }
}
```

My associated example-XAML basically contains:

```
   <Grid>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="progBar"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="10" Margin="116,175,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

But I think thats not even necessary for understanding - I think you get the point of the code, it's quite self-describing

Comment: tried it, works well on a new window only. in my app tough it's still not moving

Comment: Do not use Thread.Sleep in a form's event handler. This blocks the UI

Answer (score 0):

Just [Refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) The Control:

```
myProgressBar.Refresh();
```